# Real-time client-server interactivity using Websharper

Tags: websharper

I'm just learning Websharper but, in the short term, I have a business problem that I am trying to solve. I've written a server and WPF-based client that allows the user to vary inputs using controls like sliders and obtain feedback from the server in real-time (i.e. there is no "submit" button).

I'd like to convert this desktop GUI app into a web app using Websharper. How might I do the background request-response to the server triggered by the user sliding and slider and resulting in feedback visualized asynchronously in the web page?

Comment: Did you see http://www.websharper.com/samples/Chat ?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine the most obvious way is to simply make a bunch of `[<Rpc>]`-decorated methods for your server-side logic and then simply invoke them on any change in the UI. IIRC, Websharper handles the client-server transition transparently, i.e. if you call a server method, the necessary proxy will fire to get you the results.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out you may rely on RPC methods, but this might give unacceptable latency.

At IntelliFactory we are now working on a project that required asynchronous bi-directional and low-latency communication between the server and the client.  We ended up using the WebSocket protocol.  We are planning to document and release the code into a reusable library soon for people with similar requirements.

The prime advantage of the WebSocket protocol for our purpose was that it allowed to maintain state on the server side of the connection.  Our server is a worker role running in Windows Azure.  The server is selected randomly by the Azure load balancer when the WebSocket connection is established, and the client talks to the same server while the connection is open.  This allows maintaining expensive to initialize per-connection state on the server.

The disadvantage of the WebSocket protocol is lack of support by older browsers. A portable low-latency alternative is SignalR that uses some form of HTTP polling to emulate the functionality on older browsers.  Unfortunately we have so far failed to adapt SignalR to our requirements on Azure.  It should theoretically be possible but since AFAIK SignalR follows a mostly stateless design this would require coding up a router to redirect messages and "undo" the effects of Azure load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know integration points of WebSharper, but Rx has many nice concepts and functions for functional and reactive event processing like throttling (needs for slider and async network calls).

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS
https://github.com/panesofglass/FSharp.Reactive